# Existence of a weak-star limit of a family of operators in $B(\mathcal{H})$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, semigroup-of-operators, weak-topology

Thank you in advance for reading this question, and your thoughts.

I am working with a family of operators $(A_{s,\alpha})_{s\geq 0,\alpha>0}$ in the space $B(\mathcal{H})$ (the space of bounded linear operators on a complex separable Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$) depending on two parameters $s\geq 0$ and $\alpha>0$. This family is such that for fixed $\alpha>0$, the mapping $[0,\infty)\ni s\mapsto A_{s,\alpha}\in B(\mathcal{H})$ is a strongly continuous semigroup , and $$(\star)\quad \forall\, s>0,\,\forall\, \alpha>0:\quad \big|\big|A_{s,\alpha}\big|\big|_{B(\mathcal{H}}\leq 1\,, $$
i.e. the family of operators $(A_{s,\alpha})_{s\geq 0,\alpha>0}$  lives in the norm-closed unit ball of $B(\mathcal{H})$.
Next, the pre-dual of $B(\mathcal{H})$ (up to isometric isomorphism)  is $B_1(\mathcal{H})$, the trace-class operators on $\mathcal{H}$. This defines a weak-star topology on $B(\mathcal{H})$, and by the  Banach-Alaoglu theorem, the norm-closed unit ball of $B(\mathcal{H})$ is weak-star compact.

**Question 1:** I think that since $\mathcal{H}$ is separable, it follows that $B_1(\mathcal{H})$ is separable, and hence the norm-closed unit ball of $B(\mathcal{H})$ is weak-star *sequentially* compact?

Next, assuming an affirmative answer to **Question 1**, let us fix an arbitrary sequence $\alpha_n\to 0^+$.  Then for any   *fixed $s\geq 0$*, $(\star)$ above implies   the sequence of operators $(A_{s,\alpha_n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ has a weak-star convergent subsequence $(A_{s,\alpha_{n_k}})_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$. *Unfortunately*, however, this subsequence may depend on the particular $s\geq 0$.

**Question 2:** Is it possible to show that there exists a subsequence $(\alpha_{n_j})_{j\in \mathbb{N}}$ of the above $\alpha_n\to 0^+$ so that *for all $s\geq 0$* the sequence of operators $(A_{s,\alpha_{n_j}})_{j\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges in the weak-star topology in $B(\mathcal{H})$? If not, are there some "natural" assumptions one can make on the $\alpha$-dependence of the operators such that this works?

Comment: The answer to Question 1 is affirmative, here is an outline of the proof: [Separability of the space of self-adjoint trace class operators over a separable Hilbert space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1909396). For more details about the density of the finite rank operators in the trace-class operators, you can also check out Reed and Simon's *Functional Analysis* (the first volume of their *Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics* series), in Chapter VI when they talk about trace-class operators.